# Declare friend function which is defined in an earlier friend definition

Tags: c++, c++17

The following defines a friend function in the global namespace, the declares that same function as a friend

```
class Cls {
    friend void func(int) { }
    friend void ::func(int);
};
```

[clang accepts](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KxHD4mUlwbhPM6Ic) this, while [gcc rejects](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rg6WsGDIbOKfPMpe) with

```
so.cpp:3:17: error: ‘void func(int)’ has not been declared within ‘::’
     friend void ::func(int);
                 ^~
so.cpp:2:17: note: only here as a ‘friend’
     friend void func(int) { }
                 ^~~~
```

This looks like it should be fine to me, it's defining a function in the global namespace isn't it? The gcc error is pretty explicit about not liking it *only* being a friend though. Who is right?

Comment: This compiles with GCC 7.3. Maybe it's a regression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [[namespace.memdef]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#3.sentence-2):

> The friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup or qualified lookup.

The declaration:

```
friend void func(int) { }
```

*does* declare the name `func` in the global namespace. However, that name cannot be found by either unqualified or qualified lookup. It can only be found by ADL (<s>which, since the argument is `int`, means it cannot be found at all</s> [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055638/declare-friend-function-which-is-defined-in-an-earlier-friend-definition/54055721?noredirect=1#comment94957782_54055721) is steely-eyed missile man).

The only way to have ordinary lookup find this `func` is to additionally provide a declaration for it outside of the class body.

gcc is correct to reject.

Comment: I don't know if this is the case: MSVS2017 also compiles it without error. I even created an instance of the class, but never used it, then printed a line to the console, and the program compiled, built and ran without any errors. However, if you try to use `func()` it will then fail.

Comment: "which, since the argument is `int`, means it cannot be found at all" [Challenge accepted](https://godbolt.org/z/klySDp).

Comment: @Casey holy hell

Comment: I solemnly swear to use my C++ powers only for evil.

Comment: @Casey I don't know what that says about Ranges.