# Is it a bug of C++ gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20190 relative to friend functions

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, c++17, friend-function

The following program compiles with using `clang HEAD 10.0.0`

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void f( const T & );

class A
{
public:
    A( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}

    friend void ::f( const A & );
private:
    int x;
};

template <class T>
void f( const T &t )
{
    std::cout << "t.x = " << t.x << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    A a( 10 );
    f( a );
}
```

The program output is

```
t.x = 10
```

But when the `gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20190` compiler is used then it outputs the error

```
prog.cc:11:32: error: 'void f(const A&)' should have been declared inside '::'
   11 |     friend void ::f( const A & );
      |                                ^
```

Is it a bug of the compiler or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Doing `friend void ::f<>( const A & )` makes GCC happy. I'm sure this is a bug.

Comment: Dup of [Qualified friend function template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055575/qualified-friend-function-template-instantiation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filed [91618](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91618).

---

[[temp.friend]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#1) reads:

> A friend of a class or class template can be a function template or class template, a specialization of a function template or class template, or a non-template function or class. For a friend function declaration that is not a template declaration:
>
> - if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified *template-id*, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and a matching non-template function is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to that function, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and a matching function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to the deduced specialization of that function template ([temp.deduct.decl]), otherwise,
> - the name shall be an *unqualified-id* that declares (or redeclares) a non-template function.

That third bullet should allow this:

```
template <class T> void f(T);

struct A {
    friend void ::f(A);
};
```

`::f` is a *qualified-id* and a matching function template is found, so it should work. But gcc requires us to write `::f<>`, which is a *template-id*, in order to adhere to the first bullet.